# Python: Can we Loop inside a string?

Tags: python, html

Like for example I have a string of HTML Ordered List. Inside that ordered list, I want to write n number of lists. How can I accomplish the task of adding the lists to this string?

Here is the example code:

```
    html = """
    <ol>
      <li>
        <!--Something-->
      </li>
      ... <!--n lists-->
      {}                   #str().format()
      <li>
        <!--Something-->
      </li>
    </ol>
    """
    for li in html_lists: #where li is <li>...</li> and is inside the python list.
      html.format(li)
```

As far as I know, Strings are immutable and `.format()` will add `<li>` at `{}`. Hence this won't work for more than one `<li>`.

Comment: `html.format('\n'.join(html_lists))`?

Comment: .format() will  not add <li> at {} it will create a new string that has li in the place of {}

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, strings are immutable so just having `html.format(li)` on a line by itself won't do anything, you need to do `html = html.format(li)` because the first version won't modify `html` in place, it will return a result.

As for using a loop with `str.format()`, you should be able to use the following assuming each element in `html_lists` is a string that contains a single `<li>` entry:

```
html = html.format('\n'.join(html_lists))
```

This works because `'\n'.join(html_lists)` will construct a single string from your list of strings, which can then be passed to `html.format()` to replace the single `{}` with the content from every element in `html_lists`.  Note that you could also use `''.join(html_lists)`, the newline is just there to make it more readable when `html` is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to build HTML:

```
import lxml.html as LH
import lxml.builder as builder
html_lists = 'one two three'.split()
E = builder.E
html = (
    E.ol(
        *([E.li('something')]
          + [E.li(item) for item in html_lists]
          + [E.li('else')])
        )
    )

print(LH.tostring(html, pretty_print=True))
```

prints

```
<ol>
<li>something</li>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>else</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is really good for processing text, so here's an example using it to do what you want:

```
import textwrap

def indent(amt, s):
    dent = amt * ' '
    return ''.join(map(lambda i: dent+i+'\n', s.split('\n')[:-1])).rstrip()

ordered_list_html = textwrap.dedent('''\
    <ol>
    {}
    </ol>
''')

# create some test data
html_lists = [textwrap.dedent('''\
    <li>
      list #{}
    </li>
    ''').format(n) for n in xrange(5)]

print ordered_list_html.format(indent(2, ''.join(html_lists)))
```

Output:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    list #0
  </li>
  <li>
    list #1
  </li>
  <li>
    list #2
  </li>
  <li>
    list #3
  </li>
  <li>
    list #4
  </li>
</ol>
```